# Can't use a class from a script in another script

Tags: javascript, html, class

This is a basic problem I guess, but I can't find what the problem is. I have two scripts, one "main" and one containing a basic class, I try to instantiate the class in the main script like this:

Script.js

```
window.onload = function() {
    var car = new Card('Ressources/Sprites/Axel.png', [50, 50]); 
}
```

Card.js

```
class Card {
    constructor(path, position) {
        this.position = position; 
        this.texture = PIXI.Texture.from(sprite);
        this.card = PIXI.Sprite(texture); 
        this.setPosition(position);
    }
    
    function setPosition(position){
        card.x = position.x;
        card.y = position.y;
    }
}
```

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <style>* {padding: 0; margin: 0}</style>
    <script src="Ressources/Libraries/pixi.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Card.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
    <body>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

In the console I have this error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Card is not defined
> at window.onload

Comment: just try [JavaScript module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) will help you

Comment: Also the style and script tags belong in the head or the body, not in between

Comment: Sounds like the external file is not being loaded. Look at the network tab, do you have 404s?

Comment: @mplungjan You're right - I assumed the nature of the question before I had finished reading it and didn't see that it was being imported onload. Have deleted my comment